# Semantic UI rating star is not working

Tags: rating, semantic-ui

I am a newbie to semantic. I am trying out with rating feature but the stars are not showing up.

[Here is the plunker code](http://plnkr.co/edit/35XLHAoJSCkOb90JLxHG?p=preview)

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="image">
        img tag
    </div>
    <div class="extra">
        Rating:
        <div class="ui star rating" data-rating="4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add this line:

```
 $('.ui.rating')
    .rating()
  ;
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oSQYMqfS2rskdIM9dzA9?p=preview)